# OpenGL шейдеры: стоит ли переходить на них?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, шейдеры

Стоит ли сейчас переезжать с `glBegin` на шейдеры? Зачем их вообще ввели? Для каждого вида отрисовки свой писать что ли?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Стоит, потому что, начиная с OpenGl es 2.0 для мобильных и opengl 3.2 для настольных отрисовка осуществляется исключительно при помощи шейдеров. Если Вы планируете использовать opengl в своей профессиональной деятельности - однозначно изучайте шейдеры и новые версии opengl. Кроме того, тут всплывают нюансы с поддержкой той или иной версии конкретной видеокартой и extensions.

Answer (score 8):

Шейдеры исполняются прямо на процессоре видеокарты, освобождая центральный процессор для более важных задач. Заодно уменьшается время работы, так как видеокарта по определению менее загружена вычислениями, да еще и не нужно туда-сюда перекидывать данные - шейдеры работают с данными сразу в  видеопамяти.

Насчет того, стоит переходить или нет - зависит от конкретной ситуации. Сферически в вакууме - стоит.

Answer (score 6):

помимо шейдеров можно перейти еще и на вершинные буфферы (vbo или на vao), будет еще больший прирост производительности за счет хранения данных вершин на видеокарте, и быстрого обращения к памяти